# Visiting Israel from Schengen area

Tags: schengen, europe, israel, tel-aviv

I'm a US citizen with a passport traveling in Europe. I have a question regarding staying in the EU. My understanding is that I can only stay 90 days within a 180 day period in the Schengen area.

I was interested to visit Israel and return back to Europe however I've read they do not stamp your passport. If I visit Israel from EU would this still count against my 90 days?

Comment: What counts is the exit stamp for whichever Schengen zone country you leave from to go to Israel. What Israel chooses to do about stamping passports is not relevant. [How does the 90-180 day rule work](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)

Comment: Also, just to be careful about terminology: Europe, EU, and Schengen zone are not the same thing :-) https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area_en

Answer (score 6):

You'll get an exit stamp when you board your flight to Israel. In addition, instead of a stamp you'll get a slip when you enter and exit Israel that you can use as evidence of your status and duration of stay.

Comment: Israel does not issue anything upon exit, you just get the one slip when you are admitted.

Comment: @Ozzy you get a slip on exit that you need to use to pass the automatic gates.

Comment: I see, I don't have a biometric passport so I had to go to the guard. Didn't receive anything.

Answer (score 2):

Israel is not in the Schengen region so the answer is no. It doesn't matter how Israel handles immigration.